# Converting jest test to typescript: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, yarn-v2

I was following the [simple and well-written docs from jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started), and I got this test working properly:

```
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');

const ls = spawnSync('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);
const unexistent = spawnSync('thiscommandshouldnotexist', ['-lh', '/']);

test('spawnSync1', () => {
    expect(ls.error).toBe(undefined);
});
test('spawnSync2', () => {
    expect(unexistent.error).not.toBe(undefined);
});
```

Now, I wanted to switch to typescript, so I renamed the above file to have `.ts` extension, invoked `yarn add --dev ts-jest` (because I prefer to not use Babel) in the command line, and added this import as advised in the docs: `import {describe, expect, test} from '@jest/globals';`

However, after doing the above, I get this error message when calling `yarn jest`:

> /Users/knocte/Documents/Code/myrepo/somefilename.test.ts:1
> ({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { describe, expect, test } from '@jest/globals';
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
> at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1678:14)

Am I following the guide in a wrong way? Did I miss any step? In the guide, there's no module defined in the code snippet.

**UPDATE**: I've tried running the commands `yarn add --dev ts-node` and `yarn jest --init`, to no avail, yielding this new error message:

```
% yarn jest
yarn run v1.22.19
$ /Users/knocte/Documents/Code/myrepo/node_modules/.bin/jest
Error: Jest: Failed to parse the TypeScript config file /Users/knocte/Documents/Code/myrepo/jest.config.ts
  Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
- /Users/knocte/Documents/Code/myrepo/node_modules/ts-node/dist/util.js
- /Users/knocte/Documents/Code/myrepo/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js
    at readConfigFileAndSetRootDir (/Users/knocte/Documents/Code/myrepo/node_modules/jest-config/build/readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.js:136:13)
    at async readConfig (/Users/knocte/Documents/Code/myrepo/node_modules/jest-config/build/index.js:216:18)
    at async readConfigs (/Users/knocte/Documents/Code/myrepo/node_modules/jest-config/build/index.js:404:26)
    at async runCLI (/Users/knocte/Documents/Code/myrepo/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:182:59)
    at async Object.run (/Users/knocte/Documents/Code/myrepo/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js:155:37)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

When using jest with typescript it's actually better to look at this reference guide instead: https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/installation/

I did follow it and I didn't have any of the problems above.